# Solr for different accounts in a system

Tags: solr

I'm working on a SaaS which have a database for each account, with basically the same tables. What's the best way to index all databases separately? I was thinking about setting different solr instances(different ports) for each database in the same server, but it could be hard on the server. So, i'm in this crazy doubt on what to do next. I haven't found any useful idea in the solr documentation. Could you guys help out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you store all the data from all of your tenants on one collection, it will be easy in the beginning because probably you will do several changes on your schema and it is easier if you do them once for all your customers.
As a negative point in this scenario you will have lots of unrelated data grouped together and you always have to use a filter query for the tenant (client) id.

What if you create, for starters, a collection for each of the tenant on the same Solr server? This way you don't mix the data of your tenants and you achieve the functionality you basically need.
In this scenario, as it happens for your relational database instances, you have to keep the schema changes in sync.

For relational databases there are tools like [flyway](https://flyway.org/) or [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) that can be used to version the changes applied on each of the tenant database.

For Solr there aren't AFAIK such tools, but you can apply your schema changes programmatically through [Solr Schema API](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Schema+API). In case you have to do highly detailed changes that can't be done via the Schema API, you can replace the schema.xml file of each collection  with an updated version of it and restart the solr server.

What you need to keep in mind is backward compatibility. Whenever you add some changes to any of the databases (relational DB or Solr) you need to take into account that the old code must still work with the latest updates that you perform on the relational database/ solr schema structure.

Comment: I think having a collection per tenant is really the best way to follow. I'm also going to take a look at flyway and liquidbase. Thanks a lot @marius_neo , for the help.